# EF Query - single VM field to multiple DB properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Trying to use a single field for a search of a customer by name within my searchViewModel.  In the customer database model, name is represented with 4 properties (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `MiddleName`, & `NickName`).

```
var names = search.Name.Trim().Split(' ').OrderBy(s => s).Select(s => s.ToLower());

.WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Name), a => names.Contains(a.NickName.ToLower()) || names.Contains(a.FirstName) || names.Contains(a.LastName.ToLower()))
```

`WhereIf` may not look familiar to you, but it essentially only adds this if statement to the query if the first result is true.  In this example, if the search property for name isn't null or empty, I try to find all records where the name field could be represented.

Searching for "enn" when there are 15 different "Jennifer" records brings back ZERO results.  Are we way off base in our line of thinking on how to execute this query?

Comment: That's not going to compile as-is.  Could you present the actual code or enough of it that it isn't unformatted and syntactically wrong?

Comment: @jeffdot I intentionally am only showing the one line for the where clause...  Rest assured, there is something that looks like `return db.customers.Where(a => a.isactive)......`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a binary-or, not conditional. With the conditional-or, if the first criteria evaluates as false, the rest are not evaluated. Presumably, when you search for 'enn' you are getting 0 results because there are no Customers with 'enn' NickNames.

If you change the "`||`" in your `Where()` clause to "`|`" it should give you the results you are looking for.

**[EDIT]**

If you are able to use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), `PredicateBuilder` should enable you to do what you are looking for.

So, given a list of dummy customers:

```
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>() 
    {
        new Customer { FirstName = "Jenn", LastName = "Doe" },
        new Customer { FirstName = "Jennifer" },
        new Customer { FirstName = "Jenn Doh" },
        new Customer { FirstName = "Bob" },
        new Customer { FirstName = "Love", LastName = "Jenn" },
        new Customer { FirstName = "Jennifer", MiddleName = "Love", LastName = "Hewitt", NickName = "J Love" },
        new Customer { FirstName = "J", LastName = "Love" }
    };
```

... and a given input value:

```
string input = "Love"; // 3 results
```

... split the "name" string from your "single-field" into an array like in your example:

```
var parseName = input.Trim().Split(' ').OrderBy(s => s).Select(s => s.ToLower());
```

... and using PredicateBuilder, loop through the array and build the expression you want to use in your Where() clause:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Customer>(); 

foreach (var item in parseName)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(m => m.FirstName.Contains(item) | m.LastName.Contains(item) | m.MiddleName.Contains(item) | m.NickName.Contains(item));
}
```

... and execute your query:

```
var results = db.Customers.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
```

**AsExpandable()** is needed if using EF.

This should bring back 3 results, as in the List() there were three examples that had 'Love' in either the First, Last, Middle, or NickName fields.

Hope this helps!

**[Note]** - I have not tested this in terms of db performance, it may not be suitable for searching over 100k records. I believe this is still the best answer using EF and LINQ to Entities.

Comment: This would work well if only a single name was passed in through the viewmodel.  Suppose your field is called Name and someone could type "john" "Jo" "John Do" or "John A Doh"...  

Your example wouldn't work for any of these but maybe the first two.

Comment: I see - you should be using the binary or operator not the conditional... I'll update my answer

Comment: no change in results in doing so.  I beleive that @Mayoor's explanation of the String.Contains which is essentially an IndexOf compared to the List.Contains which is a full value search...

Comment: If you're able to install LINQKit, I have a solution for you. I haven't tested the db performance, but presumably it should work. Let me know and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `names.Contains` calls in your Linq clause is not `String.Contains`; it is `IEnumerable<string>.Contains`. Therefore, it is doing a full comparison, not whether it exists inside of the string.

The only way I can think of doing this is something like:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = search.Name.Trim().Split(' ').OrderBy(s => s).Select(s => s.ToLower());

IQueryable<User> users = db.Users;
foreach (string name in names)
{
    users = users.Where(u => u.NickName.ToLower().Contains(name) || u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(name) || u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(name));
}
return users.ToList();
```

Comment: The `.ToList` call in the end will end up querying the database with SQL along the lines of `SELECT ... FROM Users WHERE (LOWER(NickName) LIKE @p0 OR LOWER(FirstName) LIKE @p0 OR LOWER(LastName) LIKE @p0) AND (LOWER(NickName) LIKE @p1 OR LOWER(FirstName) LIKE @p1 OR LOWER(LastName) LIKE @p1)`. Assuming you don't have too many names to search for, it won't be too complex of a query.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I ended up with.  Essentially used the any on the ienumerable Names object and then looked to see if that "name" from names (or any of them) were contained in the DB property such as NickName.  This did solve the issue.

```
.WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Name), a=> names.Any(b => a.NickName.Contains(b) || a.FirstName.Contains(b) || a.LastName.Contains(b)))
```

Comment: FYI, this has been flagged as low quality. I'm guessing because there's no explanation about why your code fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to use a single field for a search of a customer by name within
>   my searchViewModel. In the customer database model, name is
>   represented with 4 properties (FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, &
>   NickName).

To me there are two parts to this problem, the GUI parsing for the search and the back-end filter.

If you have a strong typed model of Person, with FirstName, LastName, MiddleName and NickName fields, the filtering of the collection is simple.  Assume you have a list of Person

```
List<Person> mylist = GetPersons();
var stuff = mylist.where(p=>p.FirstName.Contains(firstname) 
&& p.LastName.Contains(lastname) ...
```

If you don't have a model for the query it's simple to create the class, but here's the cool thing when issuing a query you can use EF SQLQuery and pass in a type and SQL will create strong typed results like this:

```
//allow the db to do the work 
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons(){
  using(var db = new MyEntities()){
  var stuff = db.Database.SqlQuery<Person>(querystring, parameters); 
  return stuff.ToList();
}}
```

you are using a single field as input then of course the parsing is highly important because users will not follow the rules (in general) this makes the parsing more important.  For that you can either use as you have shown the built in string functions or REGEX.  I think the other answers give good advise on the front-end parsing